# Constant errors for missing symbols in equation environment

Tags: math-mode, errors

I realise this sounds like a daft question, but I have a lot of missing symbols coming up in my work, but they are there!

One such example is

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:rgbtohsb}
\begin{center}
$Hue = \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{g - b}{max(r,g,b)- min(r,g,b)} & \quad \text{if } & max(r,g,b) =  r\\
\frac{b-r}{max(r,g,b)- min(r,g,b)} & \quad \text{if } & max(r,g,b) = g \\
\frac{r-g}{max(r,g,b)- min(r,g,b)} & \quad \text{if } & max(r,g,b) = b \\
\end{array}

Saturation = \left \{ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \text{if } & r = g = b\\
\frac{max(r,g,b)}{V} & \quad \text{ otherwise} \\
\end{array} $

$Value = max(r,g,b)$

$Lightness = \frac{1}{2}(max(r,g,b) + min(r,g,b)) $
\end{center}
\end{equation}
```

As you can see I do indeed have all of the `$`. Also I have the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}`

Another error, is that it says `\begin{document}` ended by `\end{equation}`

Here is the header I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{program}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\fancyplain{}{\today}}
\cfoot{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
{\tiny }
```

I do have an `\end{document}`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't change in math-mode (started by `\begin{equation}` to inline-math-mode (`$`) as far as I know. Also i don't think you can use `center` in an `equation`, but I didn't test it.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with TeXstudio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are four mistakes in your example.

- You don't need `\begin/end{center}` for displayed equations; they are centred by default.
- You don't need dollar signs inside an equation environment; you are in maths mode already.
- You can't have `\left` without a matching `\right`, though you can use `\right.` if you don't want the right delimiter.
- You can't have empty lines inside an equation environment.

A corrected version (with unnecessary material removed) is as follows. If you don't want the equations to be numbered, you can use `equation*` in place of `equation`, and you can abbreviate`\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation*}` to `\[` and `\]`. Finally, note that there are predefined commands `\max` and `\min` which produce better results than just typing 'max' and 'min'.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:rgbtohsb}
\text{Hue} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{g - b}{max(r,g,b)- \min(r,g,b)} & \quad \text{if } & \max(r,g,b) =  r\\
\frac{b-r}{max(r,g,b)- \min(r,g,b)} & \quad \text{if } & \max(r,g,b) = g \\
\frac{r-g}{max(r,g,b)- \min(r,g,b)} & \quad \text{if } & \max(r,g,b) = b \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\text{Saturation} = \left \{ \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \text{if } & r = g = b\\
\frac{\max(r,g,b)}{V} & \quad \text{ otherwise} \\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\text{Value} = \max(r,g,b)
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\text{Lightness} = \frac{1}{2}(\max(r,g,b) + \min(r,g,b))
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) (which is automatically loaded when you load `mathtools`) provides lots of other environments for formatting mathematics, some of which (e.g. `gather`) may be better than `equation`, depending on the structure of your actual document. You might also find it useful to read the [Not so Short Introduction to LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english).

Comment: `\[ \]` is unnumbered, `equation` is numbered. It could appear that the OP wished a single number for everything, in which case one could replace `center` with `gathered`. Last suggestion, perhaps use `\max` and `\min`?

Comment: @Guido --- Indeed. I was thinking of `equation*`.

Comment: Sorry for nagging, but one more thing: I think one generally should not have several `equation`s in sequence, but rather use a `gather`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. --- I wasn't sure exactly what result the OP wanted, so I just fixed the errors. However, I have added a link to the `amsmath` documentation.